# Kubernetes Network Policy for External Name Service

Tags: kubernetes, weave, calico

We are looking at setting up network policies for our Kubernetes cluster. However in at least one of our namespaces we have an ExternalName service ([kubernetes reference - service types)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#publishing-services---service-types) for an AWS RDS intance. We would like to restrict traffic to this ExternalName service to be from a particular set of pods, or if that is not possible, from a particular namespace. Neither the [namespace isolation policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/networkpolicies/#configuring-namespace-isolation-policy) or the [NetworkPolicy resoure](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/networkpolicies/#the-networkpolicy-resource) seem to apply to ExternalName services. After searching the documentation for both [Weave](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/features/#network-policy) and [Project Calico](http://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.0/getting-started/kubernetes/tutorials/advanced-policy), there doesn't seem to be any mention of such functionality.

Is it possible to restrict network traffic to an ExternalName service to be from a specific set of pods or from a particular namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do that. ExternalName services are a DNS construct. A client performs a DNS lookup for the service and kube-dns returns the CNAME record for, in your case, the RDS instance. Then the client connects to RDS directly.

There are two possible ways to tackle this:

1. Block just DNS lookups (pods can still connect to the DB if they know the IP or fully qualified RDS hostname):

   - change namespace isolation to support ExternalName services
   - make kube-dns figure the client pod behind each request it gets
   - make kube-dns aware of namespace isolation settings and apply them, so it only returns CNAME records to authorized pods
2. Return DNS lookups, but block RDS connections:

   - extend NetworkPolicy somehow to also control egress traffic
   - blacklist/whitelist RDS IPs wholesale (easier said than done, since they are dynamic) or make the network controllers track the results from DNS lookups and block/allow connections accordingly.

In either case, you'll have to file a number of feature requests in Kubernetes and downstream.

Source: I wrote the EN support code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also posted this question in the sig-network channel in the K8S Slack community. A Calico employee and a Weave employee replied. Project Calico supports [egress policies](http://docs.projectcalico.org/master/getting-started/kubernetes/tutorials/advanced-policy) and Weave has an [issue](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/2624) to support the [K8S proposal for egress policies](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yAPpjdIV6aq7qteVIoYUbagE27jYn-6pnA8UXLAr078). It does seem as if the discussion regarding egress has stalled a little.